# Does JS creates many scopes while using for loop and let?

Tags: javascript, scope

```
for(let i = 0;i<buttons.length;i++){
   buttons[i].onclick = function(){
      console.log(i);
   }
}
```

Does JS create `buttons.length` scopes in global scope? Or JS only creates one scope in global?

Comment: You need to add a bit more code get a good answer, from here `buttons` seems to be a global variable

Comment: I this case you are making `buttons.length` different anonymous functions, each with its own scope.

Comment: Yes, for each loop iteration a new `i` is created because you are using let. if you use `var` then all the event handlers will have one reference to i and all console logs would log the length of the buttons array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why using [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/el/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) instead of [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) to define `i` makes each button, when clicked, to log the *correct* `i` is, because `let` defines `i` inside the `for` loop while `var` defines it outside the loop.

**Using `let`:**

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");

for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) buttons[i].onclick =()=> console.log(i);
```

```html
<button>0</button>
<button>1</button>
<button>2</button>
```

**Using `var`:**

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");

for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) buttons[i].onclick =()=> console.log(i);
```

```html
<button>0</button>
<button>1</button>
<button>2</button>
```

---

Before `let` was introduced, one would have to come up with *fancy* ways to pass `i` inside the function, such as using an [Immediately Invoked Function Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE).

**Using an `IIFE`:**

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");

for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].onclick = (function (i) {
    return ()=> console.log(i);
  })(i);
}
```

```html
<button>0</button>
<button>1</button>
<button>2</button>
```